# Folium of Descartes derivative at $0$

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, implicit-differentiation

With regard to this curve:
$$3xy=x^3+y^3$$
I understand that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not defined at $(0,0)$, but, there must be some more information right as there are $2$ tangent lines. I know my question is not very specific but if anyone can elaborate on the derivative as we approach $(0,0)$. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you understand that the Folium of Descarte has certain 'tangent-like' directions at the origin $(0,0)$.  However (since there are two directions), we cannot identify them by computing the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$, so it would be nice to have some other way of finding them.

One way is to use polar coordinates.  In polar coordinates, $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin \theta$.  There, our problem comes into focus: the origin $(x,y) = (0,0)$ can be represented as $r = 0$ with no restriction on $\theta$.  However, if we write down the equation in polar, we find
$$r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta = r^3 \left(\sin^3 \theta + \cos^3 \theta\right)$$
Notice that the left-hand side has two powers of $r$, while the right-hand side has three.  This means that, to keep the equation balanced, as $r \to 0$, $\sin \theta \cos \theta$ must go to $0$.  The only way for this to happen is if $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} n$ for some natural number $n$.  From this, we can conclude that the 'tangent-like' directions at $(0,0)$ are vertical and horizontal, which agrees with the image Wikipedia has of the curve.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don’t understand your Lin, “to keep the equation balanced $sin\theta*cos\theta$ must go to 0. For instance, $x^3=x^2*b, b$ in no way has to go to zero right? Other than that I really like your answer, thanks! Sorry if I am missing something trivial.

Comment: @RoshanKlein-Seetharaman No, it's a subtle point!  When you write $x^3 = x^2 \cdot b$, you are (I assume) thinking of it as a single equation to solve.  That's fine: the only solutions are $x = 0$ and $x = b$.  However, in the line you're looking at, I'm describing a curve where there is a solution for **every** $r$ value

Comment: (continued) Now, as $r$ becomes small, $r^3$ goes to $0$ much faster than $r^2$ does, so the trigonometric terms have to provide some additional 'smallness' so the equation can be balanced.  

I suppose the distinction is like the difference between a limit and evaluating a function: I'm not considering what happens when $r = 0$, but instead, I'm looking at the size of both sides of the equation when $r$ is very, very small.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your reply, so if you want the terms to “approach” the same thing it must be so? But how can you be sure that the $0$ approached by $sin\theta cos\theta$ behaves in an identical manner to $r$ approaching zero and thus assume it makes up for the “smallness”?

Comment: Additionally, concluding that $r=0$ at multiples of $pi/2$ intuitively indicates vertical and horizontal “directions” but is there a more concrete way to show that? Because the polar angle $\theta$ doesnt necessarily imply that $\frac{dy}{dx} = tan\theta$, correct? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @RoshanKlein-Seetharaman You've asked two questions, so I'll answer them one at at time. (1) You're asking the right questions!  The answer is that, if a  functions has many derivatives (like $f(\theta) = \sin\theta \cos \theta$), then at it's zeroes it 'looks like' $(x-a)^k$ for some integer $k$.  In this case, at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} n$, $\sin\theta \cos\theta$ 'looks like' $\left(\theta - \frac{\pi}{2}n\right)^1$, so we have a zero of order $3$ on the left and a zero of order $3$ on the right.

Comment: For your second question: that's true in this case (after all, we've agreed that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ isn't defined at $(0,0)$).  However, any time $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is defined, it is given by $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dr}{d\theta} \sin \theta + r \cos \theta}{\frac{dr}{d\theta} \cos \theta - r \sin \theta}.$$
In particular, when $r = 0$, this simplifies to $\frac{dy}{dx} = \tan \theta$.  (This also makes sense geometrically: can you see why?)  Thus, $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ are the natural generalizations for the tangent directions (remember, we don't have a real tangent!)

Comment: Yes I agree now actually, that makes sense. I guess this ties into Ted Shifrin’s explanation below. But this statement is only true when $y(0)=0 \rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = tan\theta$ right? Thanks.

Comment: @RoshanKlein-Seetharaman In general, yes (since $(x,y) = 0$ means $r = 0$).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach, which usually shows up in differential and algebraic geometry. It's called "blowing up" the origin.

Introduce the *slope* coordinate $m$ by $y=mx$ and rewrite the equation. You have 
$$3xy=x^3+y^3 \iff 3x(mx) = x^3+(mx)^3 \iff 3mx^2 = x^3(1+m^3).$$
Dividing out the $x^2$, we obtain $3m = x(1+m^3)$. When $x=0$ we get $m=0$ and we see that one branch of the curve comes in with slope $0$. Now make the reciprocal substitution (to see what happens with infinite slope) $x=\ell y$. Similarly we end up with
$3\ell = y(1+\ell^3)$, and, when $y=0$, we find that $\ell=0$, so there is also a branch of the curve at the origin with infinite slope.

**Comment**: By the way, polar coordinates is itself a blow-up of the origin, as we get the whole circle of possible directions $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ when $r=0$.

Comment: How can you divide out the $x^2$ for $x=0$?

Comment: @Allawonder: In the $xm$-plane, you get the union of the curves $x^2=0$ and $3m=x(1+m^3)$. The first has no information about the original curve other than to register the fact that the lowest degree term in the original equation is quadratic. It projects down just to the origin in the $xy$-plane. The other curve projects down to the original curve itself.

Comment: I was actually focusing on your statement, and not the geometry behind it. You might have used it lightheartedly, but you would agree that it could mislead. You cannot cancel since $x=0.$

Comment: What I have done is correct. I am not doing beginning high school algebra here. If $xy=0$, then *either* $x=0$ *or* $y=0$. The first case is not interesting.

Comment: Of course your result is correct. But the statement, *Dividing out the $x^2$...* is decidedly not, even if you were being cavalier with language. If $xy=xz$ and $x=0,$ then it does not follow that $y=z.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don’t really understand the slope coordinate m. If I understand correctly, by your definition, if $mx=y \rightarrow m=y/x,$if $x\ne 0$ However, both $x$ and $y$ are $0$, so $m$ should be undefined/indeterminate?

Comment: Indeed, the point is that in this coordinate system we've replaced the origin with the set of all $m$ values. This allows you to track the limiting tangent direction of a curve as you come in to the origin. For example, with $y=x^2$, you get $m=0$. With $y^2-x^2 = 0$, you get $m=\pm 1$ as the two tangent directions of the two branches.

Comment: Again, I still don’t understand how it can be calculated like this because of the division by zero. ie. I understand what is m for all points except $(0,0)$

Comment: I'm not dividing by zero. I'm using the equation $y=mx$, which holds even when $x=0$. Remember that when $x=y=0$, $m$ can take on any real value.

Comment: Ok, sorry I was being stupid and not seeing that if $y(0)=0$ and $y=mx \rightarrow m=\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $0$. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Shouldn’t evaluating $m$ provide 0 and infinity as solutions if $1/m = l$?

Comment: Never mind I suppose that infinity also satisfies the expression provided by $3m=x(1+m^3)$ because that would be indeterminate on the right, and would actually got to infinity as well.

Comment: See my discussion with $x=\ell y$ to deal with the case of infinite slope.

Comment: @TedShifrin I suppose you could also interpret the division by $x^2$ as 'balancing the order of vanishing' like I have done in my answer.  We know $x = 0$ is the limit, but we need both sides of the equality to vanish to equal orders there (in the $xm$-plane).  In this case, we're not so much dividing by $0$ as subtracting $2$ from the order of vanishing (and subtracting $2$ is always fine!)