# Using implicit differentiation to find the equation of the tangent line to $x^3 -xy + y^3= 0$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus

> I had problems with finding the equation of a tangent line (using implicit differentiation) to the curve 
>   $x^3 -xy + y^3= 0$ at the point $(0,0)$.

I used implicit differentiation to find the derivative (slope of tangent line) of $y$ with respect to $x$, but in substituting $(0,0)$ there yields $0/0$, which is undefined.

Please answer the question with mathematical detail.

Comment: You should include your work so that people don't have to duplicate your effort.

Comment: How many derivatives did you get?  There are more than one.

Comment: As an algebraic curve, you see this curve  has a double poitnt at $(0,0)$, and the tangents at this double point are the axes.

Comment: It’s the folium of Descartes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folium_of_Descartes.

Comment: Chiming in with Bernard. The same in other words: the gradient of $x^3-xy+y^3$ vanishes at the origin, so implicit function theorem does not promise you a tangent, and you should not be surprised.

Comment: The lowest order homogeneous term in the polynomial is $xy$, so the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$ are both tangent at the origin.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3154316/11619).

Answer (score 1):

Via implicit differentiation, treating $y$ as a function of $x$:
$$  3 x^2 - x y' - y + 3 y^2 y' = 0  \text{.}  $$
So
$$  (-x +3y^2) y' = y - 3x^2  $$
and then 
$$ y' = \frac{y - 3 x^2}{3y^2 - x} = 9 y^2 + 3x + \frac{y(27 y^3 - 1)}{3y^2 - x}  \text{.}  $$

(Just plugging in $y = x = 0$ gives us the indeterminate form, $\left[ \frac{0}{0} \right]$, so we expect to use limits to resolve what is happening.)

It is easy enough to inspect the discriminant of the cubic (in $y$ or $x$, since they appear symmetrically in the equation), $-27x^6 + 4x^3$, to discover there is only one solution for any $x < 0$ and likewise for any $y < 0$.  Let us inspect the solution for small negative $x$, $x = - \varepsilon$.  Then the given equation is 
$$  y^3 + \varepsilon y + \varepsilon^3 = 0 \text{.}  $$
In the limit as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, we only have the root $y = 0$.  Taking $y = 0$ in the previous expression for the derivative, we get $0 + 3x + 0$ and letting this $x \rightarrow 0^-$, we find that the derivative for the solution approaching $(0,0)$ from the left approaches zero from below.  The equation of this tangent line is $y = 0$.

Repeating the analysis for small negative $y$, we find the $x = 0$.  Putting that in the expression for the derivative obtains $9 y^2 + 0 + \frac{27 y^3 - 1}{3y}$.  As $y \rightarrow 0^-$, we find the derivative is undefined.  That is, the tangent line is vertical, $x = 0$.