# implicit differentiation and taking limit on derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have this equation $x^3-xy^2+y^3=0$ and I want to know the value of the derivative at $(0,0)$. Through implicit differentiation I find $y'=\frac{y^2-3x^2}{3y^2-2xy}$. Now for $x=0,y=0$ this fraction becomes an indeterminate form. Upon graphical inspection I think if I were to draw a tangent at the Origin, it will have a slope very close to $-0.75$, but what is an easy method to find out the actual value? Note, when you graph the original function it LOOKS like a line, but it ISN'T. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Consider the approach from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3154364) also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the function is homogeneous (every term is has degree $3$), the graph is actually in fact a union of lines through the origin. Since the cubic polynomial $u^3-u^2+1=0$ has precisely one real root $u_0$, the curve is in fact just the line $y=u_0x$.

Here's a general approach to such problems, if you're interested. Substitute $y=ux$ and factor out the highest power possible of $x$. In this case, you're left with $x^3(u^3-u^2+1)=0$, so in the $ux$-plane we get $x=0$ and $u^3-u^2+1=0$. This tells us that our curve becomes (aside from $x=0$) the curve $u^3-u^2+1=0$, which we've already said is just the line $u=u_0$. This means that our equation reduces to $y=u_0x$, as we said.

Let me show you a different example. Suppose you had instead the curve $y^2-x^2-x^3=0$. If you try implicit differentiation at the origin, you have the same situation. Now if I substitute $y=ux$, I get
$x^2(u^2-1+x) = 0$, and so I'm looking at the parabola $x=1-u^2$ in the $xu$-plane. When $x=0$, we get $u=1$ and $u=-1$. This tells me that the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ are the *two* tangent lines to our original curve at the origin.

[image]

Comment: This is a very thorough answer, but I need time to let it all "sink in" as I am not such a quick learner myself. My question came after elaborating on its graph from a simple implicit differentiation problem from my Calc 1 summer class. It seems like the answer is not Calc 1 material. Thank you for your input.

Comment: You're right that the answer is a bit sophisticated for a calc 1 student, but the point is to introduce the slope of the lines through the origin as a new variable. I honestly don't think there is a solution from implicit differentiation without some subtleties. I put this answer here for people to learn from, also to explain a bit what's going on in the other solution posted.

Comment: This is very cool stuff, but not for my students I'm afraid. I am going to play with some more homogeneous equations through the Origin applying your "trick" to see what happens.

Comment: @imranfat: I'll be glad to help out more if you are interested and have questions.

Comment: Hello, the curve $x^3+xy+y^3=0$ is not homogeneous (center term is degree 2) and yet this curve also behaves very linear for large $(x,y)$. A "rough" approach would be that for large $(x,y)$ the center term "loses" against the cubic terms, leading to $y=-x$ when solving, indicating that the slope would be $-1$. This is poor math in my view, but I can't help not denying that the curve really behaves like a linear function that has a slope $-1$ for point far away from Origin. Now since this equation is not homogeneous, how is this possible?

Comment: What I'm talking about is "infinitesimal" at the origin, not global. In the case of your example, for large $x,y$, the $xy$ term is insignificant and the $x^3+y^3=0$ dominates. If you want to look "locally" at infinity, introduce $x=1/z$ and $y=u/z$ (with $z\approx 0$) and your equation becomes $u^3+uz+1=0$, so if you set $z=0$ you of course get $u^3+1=0$. Nifty, huh? :)

Comment: Ok, again something to ponder about. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from $y_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}'=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{k^2x^2-3x^2}{3k^2x^2-2kx^2}$ where $k$ appears to be $y_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}'$ itself.
This construction makes perfect sense to me (to take $y=kx$ when taking the limit) where $k$ is the desired slope, but I'm having rather hard time to explain why it's obvious. So
$$k=\frac{k^2-3}{3k^2-2k}\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
k^3 - k^2 = -1\\
k\ne 0\\
k\ne\frac23
\end{cases}$$
[Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28k%5E2+-+3%29%2F%28k+%283+k+-+2%29%29%3Dk) gives $$
k = \frac13 \left(1 - \left(\frac{2}{25 - 3 \sqrt{69}}\right)^{1/3} -
\left(\frac12 (25 - 3 \sqrt{69})\right)^{1/3}\right)\approx-0.75488$$

Comment: For $x\ne 0$, we have $\left(\frac yx\right)^3-\left(\frac yx\right)^2+1=0$ which has only one real root ($k$). This explains why $y=kx$.

Comment: The simplest explanation in this case is $$y'=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{y-0}{x-0}$$ Therefore you should divide by $x^2$ both the numerator and denominator, so in the limit to $(0,0)$ you get $$y'=\frac{y'^2-3}{3y'^2-2y'}$$

Comment: Also note that instead of solving the cubic to find the derivative, you could have solved the cubic equation to find $y(x)$

Comment: If the slope is not -0.75 as I tried to meticulously deduce from my zoomed in graph, then the beauty of math has struck me once again.

Comment: Nope, it's a very irrational number which is approximately $-0.754878$, as Alexey said. Do you remember the rational roots test from high school algebra? This polynomial cannot possibly have a rational root other than $\pm 1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I do, but I just didn't think it would be needed here as I was zooming in a ridiculous amount of times at the Origin and "derived" the -0.75. Bummer. This question turned out to be much more sophisticated than I thought. The thing with implicit differentiation problems is though, that my post is not an uncommon situation. If the graph passes through O then more than once the derivative will show this "indeterminate form" situation, hence my post.

Comment: I wasn't complaining about your post in the least. Indeterminate forms with more than one variable in them can be very troublesome and belong in multivariable calculus or analysis.